# SharePoint 2013 List info into a Certificate (using InfoPath)?

Tags: 2013, list, infopath

Here's my interesting task:
I need to be able to pull information from a list, and place it into a "certificate of completion".  I was thinking that InfoPath might be able to do this (with a little creativity), but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Could you please elaborate little more about certificate of completion... what exactly it should do.

Comment: The certificate should simply display fields in the list items, like name, completion date, etc, all of which are columns in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right using infopath you can implement this very quickly without any code.

Create a secondary data connection to your list...while creating data connection select **get data** from SharePoint list, then select all your required required columns whichever you want to display in the form. Once data connection creation is done, go to the secondary data connection, and drag and drop the items nodes to form.

Even, we can filter the list items data by applying the filter on secondary data connection.